# Using Windows, why does booting up after an unexpected shutdown take much longer time?

Tags: windows-7, windows

It's not hard to notice that booting up after an unexpected shutdown takes much longer time than after a clean shutdown.

Are any optimizations being performed during a clean shutdown?

Comment: I wouldn't say "optimisations" are being done, more "verification" and/or "repair" tasks on the filesystem. It's like if you fall off your bike, the first thing you do is a quick "check" to make sure you haven't cut yourself, you don't just jump straight back on and start riding as if nothing had happened.

Comment: @Kinnectus where do you get this "wisdom" from? Isn't it just a matter of not having the hybrid shutdown/startup being performed?

Comment: With the information provided (and, probably, quite good assumptions) I went down the route of not assuming as it could be checks or it could be hybrid shutdown... Should have asked the OP to confirm OS....

Comment: @Kinnectus that actually makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

I have to assume you are either using windows 8 or windows 10.

If that is indeed the case, then the reason is hybrid shutdown.

Many people complained to Microsoft that windows takes a long time to start up, which lead to people not shutting down in the first place.

Microsoft has responded to that by implementing hybrid shutdown.

This technique will close all programs so the memory footprint is as small as it can be, then the system will be placed into hibernation. The pc is not actually shutdown, but the memory is written to disk.

Because of this, the startup of windows is also much faster. It only has to restore the memory image, and resume windows, but it will look like a clean boot.

It is the same reason that a reboot will take longer than shutdown, startup. A reboot will not trigger the hibernation sequence either.

Obviously, an unexpected shutdown does not place the pc in hibernation either, but turns it off, so the windows kernel has to be loaded too, similar to a reboot.

Comment: I actually use Windows 7. Is there such a mechanism in Windows 7?

Comment: @Moon No. Windows 7 does not have hybrid shutdown. Its likely performing checks to see if the system was damaged during the improper shutdown and see if it has to recover. One of the checks could be checking for disk errors, and there is the option to abort that.